# How to post Array of data for FormData using react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, multipartform-data, form-data

i'm trying to send list of data using `form_data` in react-native , but it is posting first data only , how to achieve that in react native ,

My Data ,

`var data = ["person_1","person_2","person_3"];`

My Code ,

```js
export function updateUsers(data,token) {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('first_name', data); // here i need to update all the data
  
  return dispatch => {
                 axios({
                   method : 'patch',
                   url : SERVICE.url+"user/"+un+"/",
                   headers: {
                     'Authorization' : "Token "+token,
                  },
                   data : fd
                })
                .then(response => {
                     console.log("updateUser done  . . .");
                     var data = response.data;
                     dispatch({
                       type: "UPDATE_USER",
                       data,
                     });
                   }).catch(error => {
                     console.log("got error in UPDATE_USER ", error);
                   });
          }
}
```

but for now , only one data is updated at a time , so how can i achieve that .help me from this .

Comment: You have data as an array, so do you want for each item in array send a request?

Comment: Yah , absolutely bro !!

Comment: i mean , single post request with array of data .

Comment: Did you try convert object to string? Connection between backend and frontend should be on string. Try data: JSON.stringify(fd)

Comment: Tried bro , But no luck .

Comment: Do you know how to post Video using FormData ??

Comment: What do you mean only 1 data is updated at a time?

Comment: Instead of append , if u want to update all the data i.e. persons details try it with map.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 4):

You should loop through each of your data and append it into your formdata's first_name field.

```
data.forEach((item) => {
   fd.append('first_name', item)
})
```

The remaining code will be same.